# Get back on a component after DeepLinking react native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I'm using deeplinking in react-native in order to redirect the user to a youtube channel. But when I'm going back to my app, I have a blank screen, how can I make the user going back to the homeScreen ?

Here is my youtube code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Linking } from 'react-native';
import Acceuil from './Accueil';


class ChaineYT extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoading:false,
    isLinked: false
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    Linking.openURL('vnd.youtube://' + 'www.youtube.com/channel/UC1UpcbyFVTZTDrvdjNmSzSg')
    this.setState(isLoading=true, isLinked=true);

    if(this.state.isLoading && this.state.isLinking){
      return this.props.navigation.navigate("Acceuil")
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default ChaineYT
```

I'm not sure about the states that I'm using.

Edit : I've updated with the Accueil.js screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, FlatList, ListView, Linking, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import voyantes from '../Helpers/voyantesData';
import VoyanteItem from './VoyanteItem';
import MyButton2 from './MyButton2';

const numColumns = 2;
class Accueil extends React.Component {

  _displayDetailForVoyante = (idVoyante,photo, specialite, description, name) => {
    console.log("Display film with id " + idVoyante);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("VoyanteProfil", { idVoyante: idVoyante,photo: photo,specialite:specialite,description:description, name:name });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginVertical: 8 }}>
          <MyButton2 style={{}} text={"Voyance privée\nouvert 24h/24\n01 44 01 77 01"} icone='icone-transfert' onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('tel:0144017701'); }}/>
          <MyButton2 text={"Voyance sans CB\nouvert 24h/24\n32 32"} icone='icone-sonnerie' onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('tel:3232'); }}/>
        </View>
        <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
        data={voyantes}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => <VoyanteItem voyante={item} displayDetailForVoyante={this._displayDetailForVoyante} />}
        numColumns={numColumns} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#dfdee1',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    },
  textinput: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#EF3934',
    borderColor: '#EF3934',
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  text: {
    backgroundColor: '#EF3934',
    borderColor: '#EF3934',
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  flatList: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignContent: 'flex-start',
    //justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    //alignItems: 'flex-start'
  }
})

export default Accueil

``
```

Comment: "Acceuil" is your home screen name ?

Comment: Yes, it's the page that I want to get back when the user leaves the youtubeApp

Comment: So you can just call `this.props.navigation.navigate("Acceuil")`. `return` don't require.

Comment: **Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.** I have this error when I try your way

Comment: So this error may be in your "Acceuil" screen. Can you post related code from "Acceuil" screen ?

Comment: Just updated with Accueil.js

Comment: I found solution. Please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

In your `ChaineYT` you have written below line :

```js
this.setState(isLoading=true, isLinked=true);
```

replace it with :

```js
this.setState({isLoading:true, isLinked:true});
```

Comment: I got an unexpected token error when changing `this.setState({isLoading=true, isLinked=true});`.

Comment: I'm doing this :                                                                                    componentDidMount = () => {
    Linking.openURL('vnd.youtube://' + 'www.youtube.com/channel/UC1UpcbyFVTZTDrvdjNmSzSg')
    this.setState({isLoading=true, isLinked=true});
    
    if(this.state.isLoading && this.state.isLinking){
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Acceuil")
    }
  }

Comment: Ok I found my mistake it's this.setState({isLoading**:**true, isLinked**:**true}); but it's not getting me back in "Accueil". I still have a blank page when I go back in my app

Comment: So you don't have an idea why?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have any idea what's going wrong here.